# Silverlight image loading problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, asynchronous

I simply cannot load Silverlight images synchronously. ImageOpened is all well and good but it doesn't really help me if if I have 20 textures to load BEFORE the app is allowed to execute! You cannot use threads as it causes multiple cross domain / cross thread exceptions. I have solved it but I am v curious as to how anyone else has tackled this.

My requirement is to load a jpeg / png / whatever into a pixel array, as i say, asynchronous options are a no go as I NEED the pixels before I start rendering.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

you didn't say, from where you load a jpeg / png / whatever. If from resource, you can try to load first to BitmapImage, but not by UriSource property. Just use a method SetSource() - for me it loads the image immediately.

For example:

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Resources;


BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
Uri uri = new Uri("/SilverlightApp1;component/Resources/foto.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
bmp.SetSource(sri.Stream);
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = bmp;
```